# spring controller call on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I am a beginner and facing the following issue with Spring mvc and ajax.
I have a table of rows with quantity fields in my jsp page.
The initial behavior was whenever the user updated quantity field and tabbed out from the field a jsp form was being submitted with the values only from the row in focus. The form action is bound to a controller method. So the error or success on the form submit was being displayed via the controller method. This controller method has a request parameter of the selected row.

So in essence only one row was validated at a time.

There is an update button on the jsp page.Now the requirement is to validate all the rows at once on the update button click.
So all the error/ success messages should be displayed at once.

On the click of the button I am looping through all the quantity fields and submitting the form via ajax. All the values are getting updated correctly. However, the error/success messages that the controller displayed are not getting displayed anymore.

jsp page -
form with action = update, method = post.
input - quantity and selected row.

Controller - Method - Request mapping to the above action with request parameter of selected row.
-Displays error/ success messages.
-Updates quantity for valid input.
- and finally redirects to the same page

javascript - 
On the update button click-
for each of the quantity fields passing the row index and quantity and submitting the form via ajax post.. The ajax success and error methods are currently empty as I was expecting the errors to be displayed via the controller.
If I do form.submit instead of ajax it is updating only the last row.

I do not want to disturb the existing functionality of the controller as it may be used in other pages.
Please suggest.

```
JSP
….
//table with prd_qty input field
 <button type="submit" id="updateButton">Update</button>
….. . .
 <form action=“../update” id=“updateQtyForm” autocomplete="off" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="selectedRow"/>
     <input type="hidden" name=“qty”/>
 </form>
Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateQty(@RequestParam(“selectedRow”) final long selectedRow, final Model model,@Valid final UpdateQtyForm form, final BindingResult bindingResult, final HttpServletRequest request, final RedirectAttributes redirectModel) throws Exception{
    //validation and displays error messages based on bindingResult
    return “/products”
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/products",  method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public String showProducts(final Model model) throws Exception
    {..return <same page>;}
Script
$('#updateButton').click(function(e) {
    var form=$(“#updateQtyForm");
    var data;
    $('input[id^=“prd_qty"]').each(function() {
        var index=$(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];         
        var qty=$(this).val();  
        form.find('input[name=selectedRow]').val(index);
        form.find('input[name=qty]’).val(qty);          
         data =  $.ajax({
                url     : form.attr("action"),
                type    : form.attr("method"),
                data    : form.serialize(),
                success : function ( data ) {   },
                error   : function (  ) { }
            }) 
});
```

Comment: Could you update with your code ( essentials parts)?

Comment: update the code like what i have edited now in your post. so that anyone can easily understand your code.. and remove the code from comments

Comment: What are you doing in your ajax success and error functions?